# rvm install on rhel6

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm

ok, so i'm coming from a python `virtualenv` environment, so please bear with me...

i am trying to install rvm on a non-internet visible machine (ie it doesn't have direct outside access). so

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

would not work. no problems i thought, i'll just copy the file over from another machine and do a `cat` that worked, however, because rvm tries to download the source files directly from the web, it again failed....

so i found that if i put the tarballs under `~/.rvm/archives`, i can install rvm as a single user (and take up ~200MB of my home space)... however, i want to install for multiuser for production purposes and use `.rvm` directories in my project. however, my `/usr/local` is read only (afs mount).... so rvm fails again.

any ideas? i don't particularly like the idea of having a rvm user and group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can supply --path=/opt/rvm to the RVM install script to change the location of a multi-user installation.

I don't believe the RVM group can be changed as it relies on that group to operate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

hmm... so i decided to look at the rvm-install script (ie `https://get.rvm.io`). basically, it was hardcoded to `/usr/local/rvm`, so i just changed that to `/opt/rvm`.

i then also had to add a check for the rvm tarball under the `get_and_unpack` function:

```
if [ -e ${rvm_archives_path}/${_file} ]
then
  true
elif curl -L ${_url} -o ${rvm_archives_path}/${_file}
```

then download the file at `https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/tarball/master` into `/opt/rvm/archives/wayneeseguin-rvm-master.tgz`

that installed rvm fine into `/opt/rvm`.

however, logging back in will result in `-bash: __rvm_add_to_path: command not found`. this is because the `profile.d` script is hard coded to `/usr/local/`, so doing a find and replace on `/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` to `/opt/` did the trick.

however, all the files are still group'd to `rvm`. which is fine, but another group i have to justify to my unix-admin.